# How to wait for multiple state updates in multiple hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Example**

In my scenario I have a sidebar with filters.. each filter is created by a hook:

```
const filters = {
  customerNoFilter: useFilterForMultiCreatable(),
  dateOfOrderFilter: useFilterForDate(),
  requestedDevliveryDateFilter: useFilterForDate(),
  deliveryCountryFilter: useFilterForCodeStable()
  //.... these custom hooks are reused for like 10 more filters 
}
```

Among other things the custom hooks return currently selected values, a `reset()` and handlers like `onChange`, `onRemove`. (So it's not just a simple `useState` hidden behind the custom hooks, just keep that in mind)

Basically the `reset()` functions looks like this:

I also implemented a function to clear all filters which is calling the `reset()` function for each filter:

```js
const clearFilters = () => {
    const filterValues = Object.values(filters);
    for (const filter of filterValues) {
      filter.reset();
    }
  };
```

The `reset()` function is triggering a state update (which is of course async) in each filter to reset all the selected filters.

```
// setSelected is the setter comming from the return value of a useState statement
const reset = () => setSelected(initialSelected);
```

**Right after the resetting** I want to do stuff with the reseted/updated values and **NOT with the values before the state update**, e.g. calling API with reseted filters:

```js
clearFilters();
callAPI();
```

In this case the API is called with the old values (before the update in the `reset()`)
So how can i wait for all filters to finish there state updated? Is my code just badly structured? Am  i overseeing something?

For single state updates I could simply use `useEffect` but this would be really cumbersome when waiting for multiple state updates..

Please don't take the example to serious as I face this issue quite often in quite different scenarios..

Comment: The [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) documentation states *`useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one[...]*. Maybe this might be worth considering.

Comment: I know the benefits of `useReducer` but how does this help in my case? I really can not see how I can use this information for more complex scenarios..

Comment: Normally using a reducer you can define a "reset" action that will atomically return a new state with all the appropriate changes made so there's only one state change. That is a lot easier to wait for and respond to

Comment: This is true, but a major benefit of hooks are reusability. In my case I have three different filter types (e.g. `useFilterForDate`) implemented as three different custom hooks. This was working perfect so far and i still can not see how all of this comes together when using `useReducer`.. how could I reuse the stateful logic of the filters here ? Its pretty sad that there is no simple way of making or at least simulating synchronoues state updates with the tools that react provides ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I came up with a solution by implementing a custom hook named `useStateWithPromise`:

```
import { SetStateAction, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const useStateWithPromise = <T>(initialState: T):
  [T, (stateAction: SetStateAction<T>) => Promise<T>] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const readyPromiseResolverRef = useRef<((currentState: T) => void) | null>(
    null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readyPromiseResolverRef.current) {
      readyPromiseResolverRef.current(state);
      readyPromiseResolverRef.current = null;
    }

    /** 
     *  The ref dependency here is mandatory! Why?
     *  Because the useEffect would never be called if the new state value
     *  would be the same as the current one, thus the promise would never be resolved
     */
  }, [readyPromiseResolverRef.current, state]);

  const handleSetState = (stateAction: SetStateAction<T>) => {
    setState(stateAction);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      readyPromiseResolverRef.current = resolve;
    }) as Promise<T>;
  };

  return [state, handleSetState];
};
```

This hook will allow to `await` state updates:

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useStateWithPromise<MyFilterType>();

 // setSelected will now return a promise
 const reset = () => setSelected(undefined);
```

```
const clearFilters = () => {
    const promises = Object.values(filters).map(
      filter => filter.reset()
    );

    return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

```
await clearFilters();
callAPI();
```

Yey, I can wait on state updates! Unfortunatly that's not all if `callAPI()` is relying on updated state values ..

```
const [filtersToApply, setFiltersToApply] = useState(/* ... */);

//...

const callAPI = ()  => {
   // filtersToApply will still contain old state here, although clearFilters() was "awaited"
   endpoint.getItems(filtersToApply); 
}
```

This happens because the executed `callAPI` function after `await clearFilters();` is is not rerendered thus it points to old state. But there is a trick which requires an additional `useRef` to force rerender after filters were cleared:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (filtersCleared) {
      callAPI();
      setFiltersCleared(false);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [filtersCleared]);

//...

const handleClearFiltersClick = async () => {
    await orderFiltersContext.clearFilters();
    setFiltersCleared(true);
};
```

This will ensure that `callAPI` was rerendered before it is executed.

That's it! IMHO a bit messy but it works.

---

If you want to read a bit more about this topic, feel free to checkout my [blog post](https://dev.to/ysfaran/usestatewithpromise-a-custom-hook-to-await-state-updates-of-usestate-284o).